# is nthroot of a negative number imaginary if n is not whole number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I wanted to find the domain of a function which is defined as $y=x^{1/x}$
For negative $x$, if $x$ is even then the result will be imaginary, if $x$ is odd then the result is real. However, what about $x=-2.5$ or $-e$?

Comment: HINT: $f(x)=e^{\log f(x)}$.

Comment: You do know that in the complex numbers, there are $n$ solutions to $y=x^{1/n}$ if $n$ is a non-zero integer, and for irrational $z$, $y=x^{1/z}$ has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score -1):

The n-th root of a number is that number raised to the power  1/n. So the 1/3-th root of a number is just that number cubed. Thus, by these definitions, the 1/3-th root of -5 is -125, which is not imaginary. Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I think you did.  How would you evaluate $(-2)^{-\frac 12}$ or $(-2.5)^{-\frac 1{2.5}}$ or $(-e)^{-\frac 1e}$?

Comment: I do not know if the negative e-th root of negative e is imaginary, for example.